# In PHP (Wordpress), how can I alter this code to make the Google+ link target=blank, opening in a new window?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I just found a widget I like in WP.  But I don't wanna take visitors off my blog.

I edited the plugin's php file, but having little knowledge of PHP, I'm trying to figure out how I can make the follow link open in a new window when they visit my G+ page.

I'm sure it comes from one of these snippets of code in the php file:

```
/**
 * Set the widget defaults
 */
private $widget_title = "Add WHI To Your Google Plus Circles";
private $googleplus_username = "https://plus.google.com/101536806553649165592";
private $googleplus_width = "250";
private $googleplus_header = "true";
```

or

```
/* Our variables from the widget settings. */
$this->widget_title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

$this->googleplus_username = $instance['page_url'];
$this->googleplus_width = $instance['width'];
$this->googleplus_header = ($instance['show_header'] == "1" ? "true" : "false");
```

or

```
/* Like Box */

?>
<div class="g-plus" data-width="<?php echo $this->googleplus_width; ?>"
data-href="<?php echo $this->googleplus_username ?>"
data-rel="publisher">

</div>
```

Here's the current result:

[image: Google Plus Widget]

I just figured it had something to do with googleplus_username, and those are the 3 instances of it in the file.  Does anybody know how I can configure the code to open up in a new window?  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer!

Comment: This is a widget created by google+ code. I don't see any option in the configuration variables to force a new window to open.

Comment: from a quick search looks like others are suffering from this, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440498/how-to-open-the-link-in-new-window-of-google-plus-badge

and a request has been raised... 

http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=316

Sorry, but it looks like its in the control of Google

Comment: Thanks datasage, Stefan Cross, for taking the time to read my question and respond.  I suppose it's not too pressing of an issue, but like many of us, I try to perfect things.  G is falling behind on some things ... like this, and the inability to post to G+ from WP (and other sites) w/ their API the way it is ... although some 3rd party tools can do the trick.  thanks for the links, Stefan, and thanks again for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

Does the widget insert html code in your template, or is it an iframe? In the latter case you're screwed and you'll probably have to wait for google to fix it.

If it inserts html, you could always add a javascript/jquery snippet to the page, forcing the urls to do a "target='_blank'".

Something like this:

```
$("#widget_id a").attr("target","_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks jberculo ... I think I'm screwed on this one unless I find something else.  I just like this widget because it allows others to add you to their G+ circles by hovering over the follow button.  I'm sure I'll figure it out.  Appreciate you taking the time to answer!